# How to SELECT FROM the intersection of multiple subquery results?

Tags: mysql

First of all, good news: I have only 1 table.

Now, I have 3 similar queries:

```
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER BY columnA
  DESC LIMIT 600
  ) AS aliasA
WHERE (revenue > 10000);

SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER BY columnB
  DESC LIMIT 400, 999999999999
  ) AS aliasB
WHERE (revenue > 10000);

SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER BY columnC
  DESC LIMIT 800;
  ) AS aliasC
WHERE (revenue > 10000);
```

Notice the WHERE clause are the same.

Is there a way to combine these 3 queries so that I can search from the intersection of the 3 sub-queries (find rows that match all 3 sub-queries, and also my WHERE clause)?

By the way, if my single queries (before combining) can be simplified, please let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the best solution will be JOIN USING (id):

```
SELECT id 
FROM (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnA DESC LIMIT 600)
aliasA
JOIN (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnB DESC LIMIT 400, 999999999999)
aliasB USING (id)
JOIN (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnC DESC LIMIT 800)
aliasC USING (id)
JOIN my_table USING (id)
WHERE (revenue > 10000);
```

If you didn't have LIMIT in your subquery, you could have used id IN:

```
SELECT id FROM my_table
WHERE (
id IN (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnA DESC LIMIT 600)
AND
id IN (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnB DESC LIMIT 400, 999999999999)
AND
id IN (SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnC DESC LIMIT 800)
AND
revenue > 10000
)
```

However LIMIT is not supported in subquery, so you can't do it.

If you were using other SQLs, you could have used INTERSECT:

```
(SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnA DESC LIMIT 600)
INTERSECT
(SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnB DESC LIMIT 400, 999999999999)
INTERSECT
(SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY columnC DESC LIMIT 800)
INTERSECT
(SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE revenue > 10000)
```

However MySql doesn't support INTERSECT.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ID FROM

(SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE (revenue > 10000)
    ORDER BY columnA DESC 
   LIMIT 600
) AS aliasA) AS a

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM (
     SELECT * 
     FROM my_table
     WHERE (revenue > 10000)
     ORDER BY columnB DESC
     LIMIT 400, 999999999999
  ) AS aliasB
) 
AS b ON a.id = b.id

INNER JOIN (
  SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table
    WHERE (revenue > 10000)
    ORDER BY columnC DESC
    LIMIT 800
  ) AS aliasC
) 
AS c ON a.id = c.id AND b.id = c.id
```

then you can search this query

Comment: this is NOT the same with original query. Top 200 then rev > 10000 is not the same as top 200 AND rev > 10000. You will get less on the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN on key: id then put where clause at the end.  All 3 queries is making use of revenue > 10000 and it can be combined in onenwhere clause since all revenue columnn comes from the same table.

```
select t1.id from (
SELECT id, revenue FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER BY columnA
  DESC LIMIT 600
  ) AS aliasA) as t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER BY columnB
  DESC LIMIT 400, 999999999999
  ) AS aliasB) as t2 on t1.id= t2.id
INNER JOIN (
SELECT id, revenue FROM (
 SELECT * FROM my_table
 ORDER BY columnC
  DESC LIMIT 800;
) AS aliasC) as t3 on t1.id =t3.id
WHERE (t1.revenue > 10000);
```